# Flutter awesome notifications cancel not working

Tags: flutter, dart, notifications, awesome-notifications

I am using awesome notifications in flutter. When ı create notifications with scheduled can't cancelling.I use "await AwesomeNotifications().cancelAllSchedules();" method but not working. Response is successful but not working anyway.